# Friedman Test not working. Is this the appropriate statistical test?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, friedman-test

I am trying to determine if the mean distance between animal pairs changes across months. According to a Shapiro Wilk test, my mean distance measurements are not normally distributed. Due to this, I went with a Friedman test, but it is not working. Any advice on the problem or better way to analyze this data? Thanks

```
dput(head(cohort1,10))
structure(list(DeerCow = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A82118_A632", "A82118_A633", "A82118_A635", 
"A82118_A636", "A82120_A629", "A82120_A630", "A82120_A631", "A82120_A633", 
"A82120_A634", "A82120_A637", "A82121_A628", "A82121_A629", "A82121_A630", 
"A82121_A631", "A82121_A633", "A82121_A634", "A82121_A637", "A82122_A632", 
"A82122_A633", "A82122_A635", "A82122_A636", "A82126_A629", "A82126_A630", 
"A82126_A631", "A82126_A633", "A82126_A634", "A82126_A637", "A82127_A628", 
"A82127_A632", "A82127_A633", "A82127_A636", "A82132_A628", "A82132_A629", 
"A82132_A630", "A82132_A631", "A82132_A632", "A82132_A633", "A82132_A636", 
"A82135_A629", "A82135_A630", "A82135_A631", "A82135_A632", "A82135_A633", 
"A82135_A634", "A82135_A635", "A82135_A636", "A82135_A637", "A82136_A628", 
"A82136_A630", "A82136_A631", "A82136_A632", "A82136_A634", "A82136_A636", 
"A82139_A628", "A82139_A629", "A82139_A630", "A82139_A631", "A82139_A633", 
"A82139_A634", "A82139_A637", "A82140_A628", "A82140_A629", "A82140_A630", 
"A82140_A631", "A82140_A632", "A82140_A633", "A82140_A634", "A82140_A636", 
"A82140_A637", "A82141_A632", "A82141_A633", "A82141_A635", "A82141_A636", 
"A82142_A628", "A82142_A630", "A82142_A631", "A82142_A632", "A82142_A633", 
"A82142_A634", "A82142_A636", "A82145_A628", "A82145_A630", "A82145_A631", 
"A82145_A632", "A82145_A633", "A82145_A634", "A82145_A636", "A82146_A628", 
"A82146_A629", "A82146_A631", "A82146_A632", "A82146_A633", "A82146_A634", 
"A82146_A635", "A82146_A636", "A82146_A637"), class = "factor"), 
    YearMonth = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", 
    "2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11"), class = "factor"), Mean_dist_m = c(1480.32173497442, 
    1225.69175439058, 1410.5299595032, 1978.06351498649, 1982.55133776394, 
    1503.83036369967, 1338.59409701116, 2376.54211122484, 1837.12934452395, 
    2232.98351102383)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    DeerCow = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A82118_A632", "A82118_A633", 
    "A82118_A635", "A82118_A636", "A82120_A629", "A82120_A630", 
    "A82120_A631", "A82120_A633", "A82120_A634", "A82120_A637", 
    "A82121_A628", "A82121_A629", "A82121_A630", "A82121_A631", 
    "A82121_A633", "A82121_A634", "A82121_A637", "A82122_A632", 
    "A82122_A633", "A82122_A635", "A82122_A636", "A82126_A629", 
    "A82126_A630", "A82126_A631", "A82126_A633", "A82126_A634", 
    "A82126_A637", "A82127_A628", "A82127_A632", "A82127_A633", 
    "A82127_A636", "A82132_A628", "A82132_A629", "A82132_A630", 
    "A82132_A631", "A82132_A632", "A82132_A633", "A82132_A636", 
    "A82135_A629", "A82135_A630", "A82135_A631", "A82135_A632", 
    "A82135_A633", "A82135_A634", "A82135_A635", "A82135_A636", 
    "A82135_A637", "A82136_A628", "A82136_A630", "A82136_A631", 
    "A82136_A632", "A82136_A634", "A82136_A636", "A82139_A628", 
    "A82139_A629", "A82139_A630", "A82139_A631", "A82139_A633", 
    "A82139_A634", "A82139_A637", "A82140_A628", "A82140_A629", 
    "A82140_A630", "A82140_A631", "A82140_A632", "A82140_A633", 
    "A82140_A634", "A82140_A636", "A82140_A637", "A82141_A632", 
    "A82141_A633", "A82141_A635", "A82141_A636", "A82142_A628", 
    "A82142_A630", "A82142_A631", "A82142_A632", "A82142_A633", 
    "A82142_A634", "A82142_A636", "A82145_A628", "A82145_A630", 
    "A82145_A631", "A82145_A632", "A82145_A633", "A82145_A634", 
    "A82145_A636", "A82146_A628", "A82146_A629", "A82146_A631", 
    "A82146_A632", "A82146_A633", "A82146_A634", "A82146_A635", 
    "A82146_A636", "A82146_A637"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:4, 5:8, 9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

[image: Mean Distance Across Months]

```
shapiro.test(cohort1$Mean_dist_m)

friedman.test(y=cohort1$Mean_dist_m, groups=cohort1$YearMonth, blocks=cohort1$DeerCow)

Error in friedman.test.default(y = cohort1$Mean_dist_m, groups = cohort1$YearMonth,  : 
  not an unreplicated complete block design
```

Comment: Please don't delete and repost your question: just edit the original.  My comment to the original still stands: Always, always, begin with an effective plot of your data.  Here, time series plots (and even maps) would be a good start.

Comment: I appreciated your reply, but it did not address my question. Thus, I started over in hopes of being more clear, and I wasn't sure if less people would see an edited post vs. a new post. I have graphed the data in many different ways with and without outliers.

Comment: My comment did not answer the question *you asked explicitly*--that's why it was posted only as a comment--but it likely will help you provide information enabling us to appreciate what questions you *should be asking* as well as how to address the question you are asking.  Why don't you share some of those graphs so that people can understand your data? I see you have added some boxplots, but I cannot reconcile labels like "2019-05" with "Hour of Day," making it difficult to decipher. Boxplots are not as useful as the richer plots, like time series graphs and maps, would be.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed the boxplot label. I am not sure how to format the time series graph because there are so many distance measurements. I am also not sure what you mean by maps. If you have any advice on how to do those, I will get them done and posted immediately.

Comment: Please note:  It's *Wilk*, not *Wilks*. Wilks is the more famous, and really doesn't need the credit rightly due to Wilk.

Comment: If you could explain (A) how the data was gathered, (B) how the data is structured, and (C) what the research question is, then I think it could be a very interesting statistical analysis situation. As it stands, we do not have enough information to give advice.

Comment: The data were collected with GPS collars. The data were then filtered to only included simultaneous time stamps. I then measured the distance between each individual deer and all cows. For example, at 07:00 on May 9 deer1 was 800m from cow 1, 1000m from cow 2, 6000m from cow 3. Repeat for deer 2. The boxplot above represents the mean distances of each pair for the month.